# Delete records from multiple tables using Join with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, sql-delete

I'm using `PostgreSQL 11` database, I have Three related tables by foreign keys, T1, T2, and T3.
There is a Many to Many relationship between T1 and T2, so I have used T3 as a joining table.
I'm trying to delete records from these three tables with one query using `JOIN`, I have tried:

```
DELETE t1, t3, t2 FROM T1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN T3 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.t1_id 
INNER JOIN T2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t3.t2_id 
WHERE t1.col = 'something';
```

I ran this query using `pgAdmin`, it returns:

```
ERROR:  ERROR: syntax error near « t1 »
LINE 1: DELETE t1, t3, t2 FROM T1 ...
```

What is the problem with my query syntax here? Am I missing something?

Comment: You can only delete from one table at a time in Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, delete from one table at a time:

```
with t1 as (
      delete t1 
      where t1.col = 'something'
      returning *
     ),
     t3 as (
      delete t3
      where t3.t1_id in (select id from t1)
      returning *
     )
delete t2
where t2.id in (select t2_id from t3);
```

This is not *exactly* the same.  The inner join requires matches among the tables.  But I think this is your intention.

Comment: Shouldn't the `delete` statements be `delete from` statements?